# Unable to access the modal elements to download pdf with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, modal-dialog, embed-tag

I am web scraping a website that opens up the pdf I want to access in a modal view. I want to download/access this pdf.

It opens up as a pdf viewer in a modal and I can't access the download button or any other element through the Xpath.
On accessing any element through Xpath, it returns an empty list .

[The modal dialog box that needs to be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coLDw.png)

[The inspect section of the modal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SmaO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your screenshot about [The inspect section of the modal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SmaO.png) .

The element has an attribute `original_url` which is the original url of the pdf file.

And reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63635933/17493225), you can try to directly download the pdf file by configurating `webdriver.ChromeOptions()`.

So in your case it can be like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = {
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'download.default_directory': '/path/to/download/the/pdf',
    'download.directory_upgrade': True,
    'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True,
}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('your_url')

# Your code to handle the Captcha

# When you open the modal dialog box
pdf_url = driver.find_element("id", "plugin").get_attribute("original_url")
driver.get(pdf_url)

# Chrome will download the PDF automatically
```

Comment: On adding the profile element , the modal shows 'couldn't load the plugin' and nothing comes up on the pdf.